# angularjs template ng-change not called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events

I have a directive which renders appropriate template depending on the directive value. It renders a form parts. I would like to gather them and evaluate upon change of any.

If I use ng-change w/o directive, everything seems to be working fine, which is not the case when the template is called and ng-change is inside the template.

Directive looks more less like this:

```
myApp.directive('render', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        return attrs.$observe('parameters', function (value) {
            var attributes, options, renderValue;
            attributes = scope.$eval("{" + attrs.parameters + "}");
            renderValue = attrs.render;
            if (renderValue === "input") {
                return {
                    restrict: 'E',
                    replace: true,
                    template: element.html('<label for="' + element.text() + '">' + element.text() + ' </label><input name="' + element.text() + '" type=' + attributes.type + ' class="large-12 columns" ng-model="' + element.text() + '" ng-change="change()">')
                };
            }
        })
    }

});
```

It has a bit more else if's to render select, radio and so on. But the idea is the same.

[Here is the jsfiddle which shows my problem.](http://jsfiddle.net/BtrZH/47/)

I would appreciate any help on it.

**EDIT**

Wrong paste on jsfiddle, now corrected.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Obviously your posted fiddle doesn't match the question.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm what do you think about a generic implementation re-usable with ngRepeat too ?

http://jsfiddle.net/y3hUf/2/

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.directive("amount", function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: "<div class='amount'><input type='text' /></div>",
        replace: true,
        compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs) {
            return function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
                var attributes = $(iElement).prop("attributes");
                var $input = $(iElement).find("input");
                $.each(attributes, function () { //loop over all attributes and copy them to the <input/>
                    if (this.name !== "class") {
                        $input.attr(this.name, this.value);
                    }
                });
                $compile($input)(scope); //compile the input
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Credits : http://tech.pro/q/22/how-to-create-reusable-angularjs-directives-that-copy-existing-directives

Hope it helps ;) !